# How to update a 3D plot in 2 axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to rotate 8 points that are vertices of a cube in a 3D plot, but when I try to update their position in a loop their position gets updated in one axis only, and the rest of coordinates become 0.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math
 
x = [-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1]
y = [1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1]
z = [1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1]

plt.ion()
 
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = figure.add_subplot(projection="3d")
ax.axis([-2,2,-2,2])
ax.set_zlim(-2,2)
pts, = ax.plot(x[0:3], y[0:3], z[0:3], "ro")
pts2, = ax.plot(x[4:7], y[4:7], z[4:7], "ro")
figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
axfreq = figure.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
y_rotation = Slider(
    ax=axfreq,
    label='Y rotation',
    valmin=0,
    valmax=(360),
    valinit=0,
)
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
ax.axvline(0)
while True:
    x_n = [pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.cos(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 45)) if pos <= 0 else pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.sin(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 45)) for pos in x[0:3] ]
    x_n2 = [pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.cos(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 225)) if pos <= 0 else pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.sin(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 225)) for pos in x[4:7] ]
    
    print(x_n)
    y_n = [pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.sin(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 45)) if pos <= 0 else pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.cos(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 45)) for pos in y[0:3] ]
    y_n2 = [pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.sin(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 225)) if pos <= 0 else pos * math.sqrt(2) * math.cos(math.radians(y_rotation.val + 225)) for pos in y[4:7] ]
    
    print(y_n)
    pts.set_3d_properties(x_n, y_n)
    pts2.set_3d_properties(x_n2, y_n2)
    figure.canvas.draw()
    
    figure.canvas.flush_events()
 
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I tried to change `zdir` in `pts.set_3d_properties` to different axes, but it still only updates it in one axis, setting all other position values to 0.